# Robotframework- Exclude a test case from run is not working for me

Tags: robotframework

The following are 2 test cases at the bottom of my code.

```
Click correct answer 1
    Selenium2Library.Capture Page Screenshot
    Selenium2Library.Select Frame   xpath=//iframe[@title="QUIZ : QA VSTEST"]
    Selenium2Library.click element  xpath = //div[contains(@class,"ItemHeader") and descendant::div[text()="${Question1} "]]/..//div[@data-value="${Quiz1x}"]


Click correct answer 2
    [Documentation]     Capture Page Screenshot is recorded here as I use more than 1 libraries. Normally I do not need this command here.
    [Tags]  BugMute
    Selenium2Library.Unselect Frame
    Selenium2Library.Capture Page Screenshot
    Selenium2Library.Select Frame   xpath=//iframe[@title="QUIZ : QA VS TEST"]
    Selenium2Library.click element  xpath = //div[contains(@class, "ItemHeader") and descendant::div[text()="What describes best Testing "]]/..//div[@data-value="${Quiz2x}"]
```

I run the code from the command line using

```
pybot --exclude BugMute  itqa.robot
```

where itqa.robot is the name of my file. I do not understand why the test case "Click correct answer 2" shows as  run in the log.
I have the exclude command with  the tag BugMute. This tag is in the test case.

My log file show that test case run (it failed but it doesn;t matter)

KEYWORD Click correct answer 2

Documentation:
Capture Page Screenshot is recorded here as I use more than 1 libraries. Normally I do not need this command here.
Tags:
BugMute
Start / End / Elapsed:
20161023 15:15:45.277 / 20161023 15:15:46.192 / 00:00:00.915
00:00:00.015
KEYWORD Selenium2Library . Unselect Frame

Documentation:
Sets the top frame as the current frame.
Start / End / Elapsed:
20161023 15:15:45.277 / 20161023 15:15:45.292 / 00:00:00.015
00:00:00.217
KEYWORD Selenium2Library . Capture Page Screenshot 
etc

Shouldn't the intepreter skipped the entire test case  Click correct answer 2 ?

Comment: I tested your code and the Tag BugMute test was successfully excluded.
I wonder why you see your `Click correct answer 2` referred as KEYWORD.

Comment: Thank you so much. My bad, I had wrong heading.

Comment: If by chance you know how I can set up my pycharm editor with the exclude command it will be also great. I run for now on command line.

Comment: Sorry, but when I use PyCharm, I just go to its console and send the `robot --exclude WhatEverTag path_to_my_test_suite.robot`.

Comment: So is the Question answered now?

Comment: Question is answered. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Notice that in the log it says "**KEYWORD** Click correct answer 2". You have this block of code in the `*** Keywords***` section of your test file rather than the `*** Test Cases ***` section.